# How to convert $(k+1)!\times(k+2)−1 $ to $(k+2)!−1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

First of all, is it called "convert" in English or there is a proper word for this purpose?

I am struggling with the algebra, please help me convert:

$(k+1)!\times(k+2)−1$ to $(k+2)!−1$

And what is the rule for this step?

Best wishes,

Comment: ...the definition of factorial states that $(n+1)!=n!(n+1)$

Comment: You remember the definition of factorial.

Comment: "convert" is OK, if a bit unusual in this context. Instead of "convert $P$ to $Q$" I'd probably say "show $P$ is equal to $Q$".

Comment: How to convert 1+1 in 2 ?

Comment: @Student: [That proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Principia_Mathematica_theorem_54-43.png) takes some 300 pages or so...

Comment: @ The Chaz : Well, depends on your choice for axiomatic...

Comment: Follow from [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/127504/19341)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\rm \color{Blue}{(k+1)!}\cdot \color{Green}{(k+2)}=\color{Blue}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots k\cdot(k+1)}\cdot \color{Green}{(k+2)}=(k+2)!$$

There's no special "rule" at play above; if you know the definition of the factorial this is immediate.

Comment: Nice touch with the colors. I didnt know you could do that!

Comment: At least something useful from this post.

Answer (score 0):

Without need, $k$ was assumed to be an integer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127505/19341). One can instead use this [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)
$$
z!=\Gamma(z+1)=\int_0^\infty t^{z} e^{-t}\, \mathrm{d}t. \! 
$$
which converges absolutely, if the real part of the complex number z is positive $(\Re(z) > 0)$, to show that
$$
(k+2)!=\Gamma(k+3)=\int_0^\infty t^{k+2} e^{-t}\, \mathrm{d}t=\underbrace{\left[-t^{k+2}e^{-t}\right]_0^\infty}_{=0}+(k+2)\int_0^\infty t^{k+1} e^{-t}\, \mathrm{d}t =(k+2)\Gamma(k+2)=(k+2)\cdot (k+1)!
$$

Answer (score 0):

For any positive integer $n$, $n!$ is defined as,
$$n!=n(n-1)\cdots1.$$

From the above definition it follows that $n!=n(n-1)!,\forall n\in\mathbb{Z^+}.$

Hence it follows that $(k+1)!\times(k+2)−1=(k+2)!−1.$